# How do I put an Android AVD into a git repo to share with the team?

Tags: android, git, android-emulator

I'm trying to setup out team for Android development. This is proving to be a major PITA. I can make an AVD and I can run it locally. I can make it run for the git clone directory so long as I muck around with environment variables and make put everything in a .android/avd subdirectory.

But the .ini file has a full path in it, and it seems a relative path isn't working. How can I share the AVD? not everyone clones the repo into the same location and not everyone has the same username.

It seems like the whole SDK and all its tools are designed to only be used by single person teams, unless you jump through all kinds of hoops, or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Usually each person pulls the project themselves, compiles it, and runs it on their own machine or device. If those people are not developers and normally wouldn't have eclipse/android studio installed then just export the APK file for them. They could then upload it to their device or emulator of their choice and run it. If you want to look into an alternative emulator I would suggest http://www.genymotion.com/. It runs a lot smoother and quicker than the standard android emulator.